# Como adicionar uma foreign key em uma tabela já criada

Tags: mysql, chave-estrangeira

Sou iniciante em mysql e não consigo adicionar uma fk em uma tabela que criei. 
Tenho duas tabelas (pessoa, objeto) e desejo criar uma 'fk_pessoa' em objeto que receba o valor do atributo 'id' de pessoa.  As tabelas já estão configuradas para usar a engine InnoDB. Tenho digitado o seguinte:

```
    ALTER TABLE objeto ADD CONSTRAINT fk_pessoa FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES pessoa (id);
```

Então me retorna isso:

> ERROR 1072 (42000): Key column 'id' doesn't exist in table

Tentei seguir o padrão desse vídeo: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxUe5pttK5U "Creating Tables in MySQL 5 with Foreign Keys"

e também tentei seguir o exemplo do devmedia http://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-uma-chave-estrangeira-no-mysql/20299

Minha tabela objeto está assim:

```
    id_objeto int(4) PRIMARY KEY auto_increment  
    fk_pessoa int(4) NOT NULL
```

Minha tabela pessoa está assim:

```
    id int(4) PRIMARY KEY auto_increment
```

Desde já agradeço

Comment: A coluna id existe na tabela objeto? Poste a estrutura dessa tabela ai.

Comment: na verdade 'id' só existe na tabela pessoa eu até alterei o primeiro parênteses com (fk_pessoa) mas ele me retorna outro erro dizendo: " Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Comment: Veja a resposta abaixo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Resolvido - A primary key da tabela 'pessoa' estava como 'unsigned' então houve uma incompatibilidade de tipo de dados. Porém pude sanar muitas dúvidas a respeito de chave-estrangeira, então agradeço profundamente!

Comment: Se tivesse criado do zero como eu passei, também teria resolvido, esse erro de unsigned eu tinha detectado no soEN, por isso sugeri criar do zero. Mas de qualquer forma, que bom que você encontrou o problema e resolveu :)

Comment: Eu estava me quebrando pra entender, daí quando disse sobre criar do zero eu achei que era apenas a tabela objeto e assim o fiz, então o erro mesmo foi eu ser cabeça dura kkk, muito obrigado pelo apoio!

Comment: Na verdade, o código do final da resposta cria as duas tabelas para você já com a foreygn key em objeto kkk mas faz parte, o importante é o aprendizado que você(e até eu tive também) teve com o problema e em como corrigi-lo.

Answer (score 18):

Você está tentando adicionar uma regra numa coluna que não existe(veja o que o erro está dizendo).

Você deve aplicar a `constraint` a uma coluna já existente e de mesmo tipo da qual ela será chave estrangeira.

A sintaxe do comando é:

```
ALTER TABLE nome-da-tabela ADD CONSTRAINT nome-da-constraint 
FOREIGN KEY(nome-da-coluna-local) REFERENCES nome-da-tabela-da-fk(coluna-fk)
```

Logo, a forma correta de você aplicar a `constraint` é:

```
ALTER TABLE objeto ADD CONSTRAINT id_fk_pessoa
FOREIGN KEY(fk_pessoa) REFERENCES pessoa (id);
```

Mas para que seja aceito, as colunas devem se idênticas. Pela estrutura das tabelas que você postou, talvez executando `alter table` abaixo antes de adicionar a `constraint` acima, o erro não seja mais disparado:

```
alter table objeto modify fk_pessoa int(4)
```

Se mesmo assim não funcionar, como você não tem dados em ambas as tabelas, é mais fácil você pode apagar as tabelas e recriá-las novamente, já com a `constraint` direto no `create table`:

```
create table pessoa(
    id int(4) PRIMARY KEY auto_increment
    );

create table objeto(
    id_objeto int(4) PRIMARY KEY auto_increment,
    fk_pessoa int(4) NOT NULL,
    foreign key(fk_pessoa) references pessoa(id)
    );
```

Comment: mesmo fazendo exatamente desta forma dá um erro: ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: @Lucas_Menchone j já ha´dados em ambas as tabelas?

Comment: Nenhuma tabela está populada

Comment: @Lucas_Menchone veja a edição da resposta.

Comment: mesmo criando novamente ainda dá o mesmo erro citado acima... declarei tudo certo, e no final do seu codigo tentei acrescentar a constraint também, ainda assim dá erro...