# Adicionando uma chave estrangeira no mySQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli

Eu ainda estou aprendendo como criar tabelas no MySQL e eu estou com alguma dificuldade. Se fosse para criar uma tabela com seu relacionamento, criaria assim:

```
CREATE TABLE estilo (
    codigo BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



CREATE TABLE cerveja (
    codigo BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sku VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    nome VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    descricao TEXT NOT NULL,
    valor DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    teor_alcoolico DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    comissao DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    sabor VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    origem VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    codigo_estilo BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (codigo_estilo) REFERENCES estilo(codigo)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Para saber como adicionar uma chave estrangeira na minha tabela, vamos supor que minha tabela estivesse assim:

```
CREATE TABLE estilo (
    codigo BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



CREATE TABLE cerveja (
    codigo BIGINT(20) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sku VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    nome VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    descricao TEXT NOT NULL,
    valor DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    teor_alcoolico DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    comissao DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    sabor VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    origem VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    codigo_estilo BIGINT(20) NOT NULL
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Qual é o comando que pode ser executado em MySQL para adicionar uma chave estrangeira?

```
FOREIGN KEY (codigo_estilo) REFERENCES estilo(codigo)
```

Comment: [Como adicionar uma foreign key em uma tabela já criada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/110809/91)

Comment: Mesmo assim estou com dificuldade de entender para aplica no meu caso.

Comment: Qual é a dificuldade? a sintaxe? da algum erro?

Answer (score 4):

tente este código, funciona bem no WorkBench

```
alter table cerveja add foreign key(codigo_estilo) references estilo(codigo);
```

Comment: Simples e objetivo. Eu só não consigo entender por que tem pessoas que criar essas chaves estrangeiras utilizando Constraint. No seu caso você criou sem e funcionou.