# Erro ao executar INTERSECT no MySql

Tags: mysql

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero selecionar o funcionários da tabela funcionário que são gerentes, pra isso estou tentando usar o `INTERSECT` mas não esta dando certo, acho que a imagem diz tudo também, teria outro modo de fazer isso?

Comment: Já tentou colocar o espaço em `* from`?

Comment: acabei de botar e da a mesma coisa

Comment: E corrigir o nome da tabela para "Gerentes"?

Comment: acabei de tentar isso tbm kkkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o exemplo que você apresentou o código abaixo vai servir:

```
Select Gerentes.*, Funcionario.* from Funcionario JOIN Gerentes ON (Funcionario.Nome = Gerentes.Nome)
```

Só a uma ressalva. Na imagem que mostrou não existe uma chave entre as duas tabelas (Gerentes e Funcionario). Fiz o JOIN com o campo **NOME**, pois, foi o único campo que vi que poderia capturar, mas esse não é o ideal.

Se possível crie uma chave estrangeira na tabela, de modo que esse JOIN seja mais eficaz e útil ( no caso de haver dois funcionários ou gerentes com o mesmo nome essa instrução não vai funcionar)

[Criando uma chave estrangeira no MySQL](https://www.devmedia.com.br/criando-uma-chave-estrangeira-no-mysql/20299)

[Como adicionar uma foreign key em uma tabela já criada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110806/como-adicionar-uma-foreign-key-em-uma-tabela-j%C3%A1-criada)

[Adicionando uma chave estrangeira no mySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152381/adicionando-uma-chave-estrangeira-no-mysql)

[Qual a utilidade de usar chaves estrangeiras?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106084/qual-a-utilidade-de-usar-chaves-estrangeiras)

Comment: muito obrigado pela dica, mas como crio uma chave estrangeira? usando o codigo dele?

Comment: Por nada amigo! Na verdade voce pode criar pelo prompt do MySQL ou por algum gerenciador que voce utilize (Mysql WorkBench por exemplo). Alterei a minha resposta e adicionei alguns links que esclarecem varios ponto sobre chave estrangeira.

Comment: faz diferença se a chave é uma string ou int? no caso to usando o codigo do funcionario e gerente

Comment: Não faz, mas as boas práticas recomendam que seja um inteiro.